# deserializing json C# "First chance exception of type - newtonsoft"

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, background-process, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to save and load files from isolatedStorage based on [this class](http://codepaste.net/63vh4o) by forum member [Shawn Kendrot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054961/shawn-kendrot) that i got throughout [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760531/how-can-i-save-the-settings-in-the-isolatedstorage-while-backgroundaudioplayers).

I’m able to save with no problem but when loading then deserialising the json file I am getting an error

```
“A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' 
occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL”
```

I don’t know what I could be doing wrong, because the file is saved and it’s reading properly but not deserializing.
The json file has 4 entries at the moment, but it will have 6 later on.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong here?

It's this function:

```
public static T ReadSharedData<T>(string fileName) where T : class, new()
    {
        T result = new T();
        var mutex = GetMutex(fileName);
        mutex.WaitOne();
        fileName = GetSharedFileName(fileName);
        try
        {
            var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (storage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                using (var fileStream = storage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json) == false)
                        {
                            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                result = data;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            mutex.Release();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is occurring on this line:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using JSON_Storage_Test.Resources;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace JSON_Storage_Test
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const string FileName = “movieSettings.json";

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SaveJ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string json = @"{
                          'Name': 'Bad Boys',
                          'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
                          'Genres': [ 'Action', 'Comedy' ]
                        }";

        FileStorage.WriteSharedData("movieSettings.json", json);
    }

    //Im not sure here, what should the return type be
    //and how would i then access the retrieved data
    private void LoadJ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileStorage.ReadSharedData<MainPage>(FileName);
        Debug.WriteLine("Load clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you save you data file out of `IsolatedStorageFile` then view it by Hex viewer?

Comment: View the file by hex viewer to watching what is the first char

Comment: use WinHex or XVI32 view the file. I just doubt the leading byte of the file.

Comment: Maybe there is the answer. Please try again after remove all non-ascii char

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot Maybe you could take a look at what I'm doing wrong and show me how to send, receive and then access the data.
I tried ElGauchooo suggestion but it didn't work.
I've been beating myself silly in the head last couple of days and cannot figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is - as you pointed out by yourself - you have no clue what to do with the return value.

`FileStorage.ReadSharedData<MainPage>(FileName);` tries to parse your json string to an object of type MainPage which should have the properties `Name`, `ReleaseDate` and `Genres` (which should be an IEnumerable).

Your `MainPage` actually has no such properties, so your deserialization crashes.

Try the following:

```
public class Move
{
    public string Name;
    public string ReleaseDate;
    public IEnumerable<string> Genres
}
```

And then call `var deserializedMove = FileStorage.ReadSharedData<Movie>(FileName);`

Comment: this is the json string `string json = @"{'Name': 'Bad Boys', 'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00', 'Genres': [ 'Action', 'Comedy' ] }";` the method call is: `FileStorage.ReadSharedData<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(FileName);` The next step was to use the retrieved data, but i didn't get that far

Comment: Could you please provide the struct you're trying to deserialize this data to?

Comment: im not sure what u mean, I'm trying to retrieve it as key/value pairs.
How would u suggest!? Bare with me I'm a noob in C# :)

Comment: One of the things that has me a bit puzzled is those `T` & `<T>` in the function signature, what does it mean?

Comment: T means that you are using this method in a generic way. You can call `ReadSharedData<MyClassA>(..)` and your code will try to deserialize your data into a `MyClassA` class. Call it with `ReadSharedData<MyOtherClass>(..)` and it will deserialize it into a `MyOtherClass` object. Show us your *own* call. There you should see which type you're using - we need this class struct.

Comment: the call is being made from a backgroundAgent so it would be in that same class, is that what u mean?
The other thing i wasn't sure about was what should the the return type on the function making the call.
Maybe if u made a little example basing it on the FileStorage class on the link it would be easier for me to understand

Comment: I assume you're having some code like `MySpecialClass.ReadSharedData<MyMovieClass>(fileName);` If you have found this call, show me your `MyMovieClass` (properties and stuff...)

Comment: to simplify i did a new project and I'm calling it from MainPage like this
`FileStorage.ReadSharedData<MainPage>(FileName);`
It's suggesting we move to a chat, maybe it will be helpful, if you don't mind, ok?

Comment: Oooops, didn't notice that.
Nada bacana

Comment: I have updated my post to include the MainPage, did u see it?

Comment: well it's still giving me the `A first chance exception of type` and the other thing is then back on MainPage how do i access the retrieved values?